# Parsing webpages, using re, how to determine the line of a found string?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, web

I am lookng at a website in python using code like this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import re

aResp = aResp = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/");

web_pg = aResp.read();

pattern = "<title>Stack Overflow</title>"

m = re.search(pattern, web_pg)

if m:
   print "found"

else:
   print "Nothing found"
```

And I am trying to look at the tag after this and get the test inside of it. Is there any easy way to find out this information????
If it is simpler I could make do with something that just gives the line number of m and a way to get the HTML code of that line.

Answer (score 0):

To capture text, use the () braces like so:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import re

aResp = aResp = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/");

web_pg = aResp.read();

pattern = "<title>(.*?)</title>"

m = re.search(pattern, web_pg)

if m:
   print m.group(1)

else:
   print "Nothing found"
```

The .group() function returns the first occurrence of the match.

Comment: Can you explain this more clearly can you maybe give a example of using this to determine the live the code is on or something?

Comment: Sorry I may have not made this clear I want to look at the code and find the line that the search term is on....

Comment: Do you want the line content or the line number?

Comment: Doesn't matter now I fixed it by writing the html to a text file which I manipulated.